# Wi-Fi direct vs. Nearby Share

Tags: file-sharing

I wonder which is a faster way to share large files: Wi-Fi direct or Nearby Share.

Comment: Nearby Share uses Bluetooth, Bluetooth Low Energy, WebRTC or peer-to-peer WiFi. For larger files I would expect that also Wifi is used, in such a case there should ne not much of a difference to Wifi direct.

Comment: Nearby Share uses Wifi for sharing files. So, it does not make much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use Nearby Share.

Nearby Share uses the fastest possible connection it can establish with both devices. If it is not possible to establish a stable or secure proprietary Wi-Fi Direct connection, then it may fall back to using Bluetooth only. That will always be a magnitude slower.

> Nearby Share uses Bluetooth, Bluetooth Low Energy, WebRTC, UWB, and peer-to-peer Wi-Fi to allow users to share files and links between devices. It was first released on August 4, 2020

Have you used the Nearby Share app on Windows?

I'm able to send a 1.2GB file from my phone to my PC at 60MB/s and I'm about thirty feet and four walls away.

[image: Screenshot of Windows Nearby Share receiving file from my Pixe 7.]